# jQuery Mobile: Persistent Header gets not enhanced

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I'm building a multipage Website and from now on I want to use a single header Tag. I had it in every single page before, but now I want it persistent.

I used [this example](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/toolbar-fixed-persistent/), but it won't work with my code: http://jsfiddle.net/46g5vu88/

In my project I'm already using enhanceWithiin(), so this

```
$(function() {
            $( "[data-role='navbar']" ).navbar();
            $( "[data-role='header'], [data-role='footer']" ).toolbar();
        });
```

is redundant in my code. Btw, I'm using Intel XDK to build a mobile app.

Can someone help me to get this toolbar looking normal?

Comment: you should add `data-theme="a or b"` to any external widget. or `.toolbar({"theme":"a"});` http://jsfiddle.net/46g5vu88/1/

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. (Post as answer)